# Memoizing in PostScript

Tags: fibonacci-sequence, memoization, postscript

The `pusherr` and `poperr` procedures maintain an internal stack as a lisp-like 
linked-list. It's a little slower than an earlier stackwise 
version according to naive testing. It allocates lots of 2- and 3- element 
arrays for its data. But the code using them becomes very readable IMO with this
approach.

The `memo-func` function generates a procedure body specified by the 
template but with the DICT replaced by the dict argument.

The resulting procedure simply pushes the local dict, then pushes an error handler for the /undefined 
error, then just does `load`, and pops the handler and the dict. If `load` does not find the needed value, it will signal an /undefined error which will be caught be our handler.

The error handler calls the procedure named /default and saves the input and output as a new definition in the local dict.

Improvements?

```
%!                                                                                                                 

<< 
/errorstack null  % [ {errordict/errname{handler}} null ]                                                           

/pusherr { 
    errordict 3 1 roll 3 copy pop 2 copy get    % ed /n {new} ed /n {old}                                           
    3 array astore cvx  errorstack   2 array astore  /errorstack exch store 
    put 
} 

/poperr { 
    errorstack dup null ne { 
        aload pop  /errorstack exch store 
        exec put 
    } if 
} 

/memo-func { 
    { 
        DICT begin 
            /undefined { pop dup default dup 3 1 roll def } pusherr 
                load 
            poperr 
        end 
    } 
    dup length array copy 
    dup 3 2 roll 0 exch put cvx 
} 
>> begin 


/fib << 
    0 1 
    1 1 
    /default { dup 2 sub fib  exch 1 sub fib  add } 
>> 100 dict copy  memo-func  def 

0 1 100 {  fib =  } for
```

The `100 dict copy` allows you to also set the initial size of the dictionary to  determine how many entries you can add before it needs to rehash.

*This code was previously posted in [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/SR_SYDypPHs/discussion) at the end of a thread which includes the stackwise version mentioned above.*

Comment: One issue I can see is it's not clear how to extend it to multiple arguments without a pattern-matching setup which would need to be implemented because PostScript doesn't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bug

`poperr` leaves a `null` on the stack if `errorstack` is `null`. Better:

```
/poperr { 
    errorstack null ne { 
        errorstack aload pop  /errorstack exch store 
        exec put 
    } if 
}
```

This leaves the stack clean and makes extra calls to `poperr` harmless. If desireable, some action could be put in the *else* case but since this code is mucking about with error handlers, it is unclear whether signalling an error is correct here.